# How can I select all rows that meet specified criteria in two columns in sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a table of orders containing order's info. Every order has a writer associated with it and a writer can be associated with multiple orders. Now every writer has an account where they need to login and see only orders associated with them. An order status can be in progress, completed or cancelled. In the writer's account they need to see orders in progress, cancelled and completed in separate tables. Now I wrote this sql query to fetch orders in order to fill in the "in progress" writer's table but dumping the result of the query return an array(0) { } meaning there no data fetched despite the fact that there two records in the orders table that matches the query's conditions. Can anyone please help me find out the problem with my query or the code in general? Thanks

```
// OrdersModel class
class OrdersModel{
    static public function mdlShowWriterOrders($table, $item, $item1, $value, $value1){
        $stmt = Connection::connect() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $item = :$item AND  $item1 = :$item1");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item1, $value1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
    }
}

//ControllerCustomers class

class ControllerCustomers{
    static public function ctrShowWriterOrders($item, $value, $item1, $value1){
        $table = "orders";
        $answer = OrdersModel::mdlShowWriterOrders($table, $item, $value, $item1, $value1);

        return $answer;
    }
}

// Calling ctrShowWriterOrders() function where required

$item = "writerId";  //column name in orders table
$value = $_SESSION["id"]; // session for currently logged in writer
$item1 = "status";  // status column in orders table 
$value1 = 1; // 1 represents orders "in progress"

$orders = ControllerCustomers::ctrShowWriterOrders($item, $value, $item1, $value1);

var_dump($orders); // output: array(0) { }
```

Comment: _Side note:_ You can replace `$stmt->bindParam(":".$item,` with just `$stmt->bindParam($item,`. The `:` is only required in the statement/query.

Comment: You use `$item, $item1, $value, $value1` and `$item, $value, $item1, $value1` as being the same. There's a serious naming problem here. Try to use more descriptive names!

Comment: @M.Eriksson editing the code as per your recommendation gives PDO invalid parameter error

Comment: @KIKOSoftware these are just variables and they just follow the same orders when passing the function parameters

Comment: Please check your code more carefully, and reconsider using these kind of vague and numbered parameters. You've fallen into your own trap.

Comment: This is the method declaration: `mdlShowWriterOrders($table, $item, $item1, $value, $value1)`. This is how you're calling it: `::mdlShowWriterOrders($table, $item, $value, $item1, $value1)`. Do you see the difference in the order?

Comment: _"editing the code as per your recommendation gives PDO invalid parameter error"_ - That is probably because you're passing in the arguments in the wrong order,, mixing up the values and the column names. The manual even states that the `:` is optional in `bindParam()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thank you so much. I had a mismatching parameters. It worked

Comment: So, did you change the names to something better? This was the cause of the mix up.

Comment: Yes sure, I should start naming variable to meaningful words to avoid self-confusion

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you for that advice, I am 6 months old in php and sql btw